# Xamarin iOS: why camera not cover the who screen leaving white on both side

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, camera

```
var centerButtonX = View.Bounds.GetMidX() - 35f;
        var bottomButtonY = View.Bounds.Bottom - 85;
        var topRightX = View.Bounds.Right - 65;
        var topLeftX = View.Bounds.X + 25;
        var topButtonY = View.Bounds.Top + 25;
        var buttonWidth = 70;
        var buttonHeight = 70;

        Console.WriteLine("Screen Width = " + UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width);
        Console.WriteLine("Screen Height = " + UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height);

        liveCameraStream = new UIView()
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(0f, 0f, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height)
        };

        takePhotoButton = new UIPaintCodeButton(DrawTakePhotoButton)
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(centerButtonX, bottomButtonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
        };

        cancelPhotoButton = new UIPaintCodeButton(DrawCancelPictureButton)
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(topLeftX, topButtonY, 37, 37)
        };

        View.Add(liveCameraStream);
        View.Add(takePhotoButton);
        View.Add(cancelPhotoButton);
```

From the image, the side was white, probably not seeing very clear but you can see the close button on the left. The camera is not shown in full screen.

[image]

Comment: Your camera preview is in 16:9 aspect ratio and your iPad has a 4:3 aspect ratio display frame

Comment: got it.. I have set the VideoGravity to aspect fit to fill the whole screen

Comment: You might want to add your solution/code as an answer....